# How to set Preview to always open files in a new window?

Tags: preview

When I open files in `Preview`, I want them to always open in a new window, not as a document in the same window.

I've tried setting these preferences, which did not work:

- Preview > Preferences > Images > Open each file in its own window.
- System Preferences > Dock > Prefer tabs when opening documents >
  Manually

When I open a `.png` image with `Preview`, it reuses the last window instead of opening the image in a new window. I can right click > "Open in New Window", but that is annoying to do every time.

Preview Version 10.1 (944.6.16.1)
macOS Mojave 10.14.6

Comment: Well, I am confused, I open many png one after another and each comes open in a new window - such that either I have to close all or quit.

Comment: After selecting "open file in new window" did you restart Preview?

Comment: Same problem here. I have two user accounts, it works in one, but not in the other. I cannot find the setting to change that behaviour. Hugely annoying, espacially as the tab doesn't even get activated, so whenever I double click a file, I then have to search for it in Preview...

Comment: Sometimes this works and sometimes it doesn't and no setting seems to really be consistent in working.

Comment: I'm wondering if opening many windows forces Preview to open a new file in a tab.

Answer (score 7):

OK, I have been fighting this problem for (literally) years. No matter what preferences I set, Preview insisted on opening new documents in a tab of a (random) window of an already-opened PDF. I finally decided to fix this, no matter how long it took.
I created a “test” account, and determined that Preview would open PDFs in either tabs or windows, depending on the setting of the “Prefer tabs...” System Setting. I also determined that Preview would honor the state of `AppleWindowTabbingMode` using `defaults write`:

```
defaults write com.apple.Preview AppleWindowTabbingMode -string never
```

So, the behavior of Preview in the *test* account was correct.

But, copying the preferences from the test account to my main account did not change Preview’s behavior. In my main account, Preview ignored the state of *AppleWindowTabbingMode*.
I finally decided to close every PDF that Preview had open, quit Preview, and then wipe ***every*** preference for Preview.
These preferences are:

```
  /Users/[yourname]/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Preview.plist
  /Users/[yourname]/Library/Containers/Preview
```

For the one in Containers, I threw the entire Preview folder away.
When I re-launched Preview, it would now open PDFs in windows, and honor the settings in both *System Settings -> Prefer tabs*... **and** the
`defaults write AppleWindowTabbingMode` preference.

I hope this helps someone else.

Comment: Hmm...  These files don't exist on my system, but I have the problem.

Comment: Moving `/Users/[yourname]/Library/Containers/Preview` seems to have worked for me in Sonoma, although all of the documents I had opened in Preview were forgotten. Could it be that after a very large number of documents are open, Preview starts opening documents in tabs?

Answer (score 1):

I also want Preview to open each pdf in a new window.

Apple provides instructions for this here, customized (use to pull-down) for each of the last 6 major versions of macOS:

https://support.apple.com/guide/preview/display-several-files-in-one-preview-window-prvw1085/mac

They may work for you, but in my experience, they do not work!

For Ventura / macOS 13, they write,

> Note: To open multiple PDFs in the same window, go to Apple menu  > System Settings, then click Desktop & Dock . (You may need to scroll down.) Go to the Windows & Apps section, click the “Prefer tabs when opening documents” pop-up menu, then choose Always. See Change how folders open in the Finder on Mac.

Choosing "never" *should* cause Preview to open each pdf in a new window.  Maybe it'll work for some. Not in my experience.

Comment: Ventura is not macOS 10. It's macOS 13

Comment: ;) I wanted to be sure that you meant Ventura 13 and not Panther 10.3